# Referencing a helper class

Tags: module, magento-1, helper

I am trying to write a helper class for my module. The helper class will provide two methods with various functionality. Can I put this helper class beside the other helper class in my .../Helper/Data.php file or should I put it somewhere else? Also, how should I reference it from other parts of Magento in order to get access to its methods?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create as many helpers as you want in your module.
Let's say your module name is `Namespace_Module`.
The `config.xml` of your module should contain this inside the `<global>` tag:

```
<helpers>
    <module>
       <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
    </module>
</helpers>
```

Now let's say you want to create a helper called `Something`.
You should place the code in `Namespace/Module/Helper/Something.php`:

```
<?php 
class Namespace_Module_Helper_Something extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract { //or any other helper

    public function doSomething(){
        ....
    }
}
```

You can call your new helper anywhere like this:

```
Mage::helper('module/something')->doSomething();
```

Basically `Mage::helper('module');` is the same thing as `Mage::helper('module/data');`

Comment: If my class is called  `Slice_CustomCompare_Helper_CookieAccess`, should config.xml contain `<class>Slice_CustomCompare_Helper</class>` or `<class>Slice_CustomCompare_Helper_CookieAccess</class>`?

Comment: `<class>Slice_CustomCompare_Helper</class>`. Then call it like this: `Mage::helper('customcompare/cookieAccess')`

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new file with your helper-Class in the /Helper folder of your module. You can load your own helper in the same way as you load the Data-Helper.

If you configured your helpers in etc/config.xml like the following:

```
<helpers>
   <mynamespace_mymodule>
      <class>MyNamespace_MyModule_Helper</class>
   </mynamespace_mymodule>
</helpers>
```

...you can load your custom helper MyNamespace_MyModule_Helper_Custom (located in /app/code/local/MyNamespace/MyModule/Helper/Custom.php) by:

```
Mage::helper('mynamespace_mymodule/custom')
```

The required MyNamespace_MyModule_Helper_Data can be loaded by:

```
Mage::helper('mynamespace_mymodule')
```

or

```
Mage::helper('mynamespace_mymodule/data')
```

Why?

```
public function getHelperClassName($helperName)
{
    if (strpos($helperName, '/') === false) {
        $helperName .= '/data';
    }
    return $this->getGroupedClassName('helper', $helperName);
}
```