# Call a function in different directories

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.6

I want to change the numbers format in magento1.9 with call the function like and call it in different directories like `app\design\frontend\ves_arcana\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml` anywhere that the numbers is in use.

Where should I define it?

```
function farsidigit($text) {
    $text = str_replace('0' , '٠' , $text);
    $text = str_replace('1' , '١' , $text);
    $text = str_replace('2' , '٢' , $text);
    $text = str_replace('3' , '٣' , $text);
    $text = str_replace('4' , '۴' , $text);
    $text = str_replace('5' , '۵' , $text);
    $text = str_replace('6' , '۶' , $text);
    $text = str_replace('7' , '٧' , $text);
    $text = str_replace('8' , '٨' , $text);
    $text = str_replace('9' , '٩' , $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: helper class is what you need. refer to this: <https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14976/55030>

Comment: thank u it is what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call method helper class, then call any where like that

```
Mage::helper('module/something')->doSomething();
```

Comment: if you need i will provide the example code